# Jquery allow only Alpha Numeric + International characters (but not symbols)

Tags: jquery, regex, validation

I need to validate a form disallowing any symbols like ❦ ❧ ლ ۝.

I found this solution which works, but it also disallows international characters (e.g german characters - **ü**).

Ideally I should also be able to allow some punctuation - eg "-", ":".

```
        if( /[^a-zA-Z0-9\-\/]/.test($('.my_textarea').val()) ) {
            isFormValid = false;
        }
```

Comment: Note that ლ is [actually a letter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasi_%28letter%29) in the Georgian alphabet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seems like you only have a small bunch of characters you want to allow, I would stick with **whitelisting** all allowed characters (instead of blacklisting the not allowed ones).
For example:

```
[^\w\-\/üäöÜÄÖ.,:;]
```

(`\w` is short for `a-zA-Z0-9_`, if you dont want the `_`, then stick with `a-zA-Z0-9`)

For further characters, just add them to your charactergroup.

Answer (score 1):

You may specify international characters in js regexen as individual unicode code points or ranges thereof using the `\uXXXX` syntax (`XXXX` representing the code point in hex). Therefore it might be a viable solution to add the code point ranges of alphabets you wish to support (it won't if you wish to support all scripts, of course, though you could apply different regexen depending on a country/language selection ).

Consult the [unicode code chart synopsis](http://www.unicode.org/charts/) or [the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Script_(Unicode)) (the pages for individual scripts contain the code point ranges in the summary box on the top right) to find the respective codes.

Example (cyrillic alphabet):

```
/[^a-zA-Z0-9\u0400-\u04ff\-\/]/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use [POSIX expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html) you'll allow any symbol and punctuation:

```
/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-\/[:ascii:][:punct:]]/
```

So, I think the best way to do that is to insert allowed symbols as exceptions in list:

```
/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-\/,.ü]/
```